# require method called by function not working

Tags: node.js, session, express, csrf, middleware

I ran into this while setting some middleware only for certain routes. In my application, I only need session and csrf on my contact page.

Here's the problem. When I require them outside and use the references in an array as a route parameter, it works all fine. Session works fine and expects the same cookie(sessionID) for every request and CSRF check passes as it should.

But, when I use a function to return an array of 'middleware', then it behaves abnormally. When I 'get' contact, I receive one sessionID, and when I 'post' to it, apparently the session restarts and I get an error thrown since I have the older sessionID. And weirdly the CSRF also expects another csrf token and not the one it sent me.

I get that it's something to do with the way I'm requiring in modules, but I'd love to get a clear explanation as to why this is happening. Do note that I am  beginner, so go easy on me :) Thanks!

```
// MIDDLEWARE FOR CERTAIN ROUTES
// This works fine!
var session = require('express-session')({secret: 'i lit fire to the rain', saveUninitialized: false, resave: true});
var csrf = require('csurf')();
router.get('/contact', [session, csrf], function(req, res, next) {
});
router.post('/contact', [session, csrf], function(req, res, next) {
});

// but this does not work
var contactMiddleware = function() {
    var session = require('express-session')({secret: 'i lit fire to the rain', saveUninitialized: false, resave: true});
    var csrf = require('csurf')();
    return [session, csrf];
};
router.get('/contact', contactMiddleware(), function(req, res, next) {
});
router.post('/contact', contactMiddleware(), function(req, res, next) {
});
```

Comment: What does this have to do with PHP?

Comment: Ah, it was a mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you tried to do this instead :

`router.get('/contact', contactMiddleware, function(req, res, next)`

edit: 
so you only need a static array as far as I can see, so why not just doing this

`var array = (function() {
    var session = require('express-session')({secret: 'i lit fire to the rain',      saveUninitialized: false, resave: true});
    var csrf = require('csurf')();
    return [session, csrf];
})();`

and then passing your array to the route?

`router.get('/contact', array, function(req, res, next) {
    res.send('contact');
});`

Comment: I did, but it the request used to 'hang', and so I called next() at the end of the function. I ended up getting a 404, and it just didn't work out.